# NextJS - useSWR with token from session

Tags: next.js, swr

I'm working with NextJS, Next-auth and Django as backend. I'm using the credentials provider to authenticate users. Users are authenticated against the Django backend and the user info together with the access*token is stored in the session.

I'm trying to use useSWR now to fetch data from the backend. (no preloading for this page required, that's why I'm working with SWR) I need to send the access*_token from the session in the fetcher method from useSWR. However I don't know how to use useSWR after the session is authenticated. Maybe I need another approach here.

I tried to wait for the session to be authenticated and then afterwards send the request with useSWR, but I get this error: **Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
**
Could anybody help with a better approach to handle this? What I basically need is to make sure an access*token, which I received from a custom backend is included in every request in the Authorization Header. I tried to find something in the documentation of NextJS, Next-Auth or SWR, but I only found ways to store a custom access_token in the session, but not how to include it in the Header of following backend requests.*

This is the code of the component:

```js
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import useSWR from 'swr';
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Profile() {

    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    // if session is authenticated then fetch data
    if (status == "authenticated") {
        // create config with access_token for fetcher method
        const config = {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session.access_token}` }
        };

        const url = "http://mybackend.com/user/"
        const fetcher = url => axios.get(url, config).then(res => res.data)
        const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)
    }

    if (status == "loading") {
        return (
            <>
                <span>Loading...</span>
            </>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                {data.email}
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to check `status` every time. what you need to do is to add this `function` to your `app.js` file

```js
function Auth({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    },
  });

  if (status === "loading") {
    return (
      <div> Loading... </div>
    );
  }
  return children;
}
```

then add `auth` proprety to every page that requires a `session`

```js
Page.auth = {};
```

finally update your `const App` like this

```html
<SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
   <Layout>
      {Component.auth ? (
        <Auth>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Auth>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </Layout>
</SessionProvider>
```

so every page that has `.auth` will be wrapped with the `auth` component and this will do the work for it

now get rid of all those `if` statments checking if `session` is defined since you page will be rendered only if the `session` is here

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ahmed Sbai I was able to make it work. The component now looks like this:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import axios from "axios";
import useSWR from 'swr';

Profile.auth = {}

export default function Profile() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();

    // create config with access_token for fetcher method
    const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${session.access_token}` }
    };

    const url = "http://mybackend.com/user/"
    const fetcher = url => axios.get(url, config).then(res => res.data)
    const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher)
    if (data) {
        return (
            <>
                <span>{data.email}</span>
            </>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                Loading...
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

App component and function:

```
function Auth({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      router.push("/api/auth/signin");
    },
  });

  if (status === "loading") {
    return (
      <div> Loading... </div>
    );
  }
  return children;
}

function MyApp({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      {Component.auth ? (
        <Auth>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Auth>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```